# How to adjust the specific data in rows or in columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, dataframe

It's a little bit weird that I used nested loop, but it failed, it shows 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable. So, does it have a better way to adjust each data in column data or row?
For example:

df

```
   a  b  c  d
A  1  3  4  7
B  2  3  5  1
C  1  5  6  8
D  2  1  7  9
```

How can I add a number, such as

```
num = 1
```

And I wanna add num to each data in column 'c', like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
A  1  3  5  7
B  2  3  6  1
C  1  5  7  8
D  2  1  8  9
```

Or I wanna add num to each data in row 'C', like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
A  1  3  4  7
B  2  3  5  1
C  2  6  8  9
D  2  1  7  9
```

How can this work? Use nested loop like

```
for row in df.index:
    for row in df['c']
```

Or

```
for row in df.index:
    df.ix[row, 'c'] = df.ix[row, 'c'] + num
```

Can somebody help me check it out? Thanks!!!

Comment: you could just do `df['c'] += num` to add it to column `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[:, 'c'] += 1
df.loc['C', :] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can do this in a simplier way:

```
df['c'] += 1
df.ix['C'] += 1
```

It is simplier, innit?